# How to click on HTML table row and send row's data to PHP (as POST)?

Tags: php, html-table, row

I need to make a table with clickable rows (for this I found some Javascript solutions).
When I click one row, a form will be filled with data from the clicked row.

But I don't know how to send the data from HTML table to PHP, when I click on that row. Data must be sent as POST, as I mentioned in title.

I have no idea how to start, so I cannot show you nothing. Using multiple forms inside one table is not allowed, `<a>` tag around `<td>` is not allowed either, so I'm stuck.
From what I searched on web, the solution would be AJAX, but I'm not familiarized with it, never used AJAX, so if possible, a non-AJAX solution would be much appreciated. If not, please show me a functional example.

**EDIT** *solved*

In the end I did it without any AJAX, thanks to ideas from **emartel** and **Guerra**.
I made a single form with a hidden input field and I submitted it programatically, after I collected the required data from the row I clicked on.

I echoed the tr tags like this: `<tr data-id=$id_from_db onclick="submit_id(this)">`.

```
    function submit_id(tableRow) {
        //get ID
        var myID = tableRow.dataset.id;

        //set ID
        var setID       = document.getElementById('order_id');
            setID.value = myID;

        //submit
        var form = document.getElementById('myform');
        form.submit();
    };
```

P.S. I tried to embed some PHP code, but I failed, it didn't shown on page.

Comment: just 1 question. If you know the solution is AJAX, how much you tried to be familiar with it?

Comment: your problem can be solved with some jquery code. Create a sample file and let us know to give you more feedback

Comment: [**jqgrid**](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) read the docs and you will have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filling your form (`name="myform"` and `method="post"`) from JavaScript, simply call:

```
document.myform.submit();
```

This should do the work

Answer (score 0):

You can put some kind of input hidden on each row with an ID. So you can use just 1 form passing the ID to submit post and recovery the entire register on server.